# ppp internet not only after restart

Tags: network-interface, modem, ppp, wvdial

I have configured my network to get internet from HUAWEI E3131 usb modem at start. So I have prepared special wvdial.conf and interfaces files:

**wvdial.conf:**

```
root@debian:/home/s# cat /etc/wvdial.conf 
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 9600
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
ISDN = 0
[Dialer orange]
Phone = *99#
Username =;
Password =;
root@debian:/home/s#
```

**interfaces:**

```
root@debian:/home/s# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ppp0
allow-hotplug ppp0

iface ppp0 inet wvdial
provider orange
root@debian:/home/s#
```

Unfortunately with this configuration the internet connection works only after restarting my debian 8. So when I turn on the pc it doesn't work but when I then restart it, it gets to work.
How to make internet start at turning the pc on? It should be wvdial because I share the ppp internet connection.

**edit** There is no dual boot, no Windows installation in the system.

Comment: I bet it only works after coming from Windows. Dual boot, or any installed  software driver? You are not telling us something, those pens do not work like that.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro There is no dual boot, no Windows installation in the system.

Comment: Do you have network manager installed, or do you use old-style ifup/ifdown?

Comment: @dirkt I uninstalled network manager to get configuration cleaner. I couldn't find any tutorial about how to share ppp connection that was managed by NM. So I uninstalled it.

Comment: Likely to be an issue with `wvdial` talking to the modem too early after power up, as described here: https://superuser.com/a/527551